# UITableView push segue triggered multiple times

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I came across a strange bug in my app:

**The setup**

A simple Master-Detail app, iPhone style (ie. no split view, no popover, just a navigation controller, a table view controller, and a view controller).

[image]

**The bug**

1. Touch a "background" part of the table view (the darker grey parts on my screenshot) like a section header or footer.
2. While keeping your finger on the screen, touch a cell multiple times.
3. Release all fingers. The "detail" view will pushed normally, but when touching the back button, you will find that the detail view was stacked as many times as you touched the cell at step 2.

[image]

You can also touch multiple cells at step 2 and their destination views will be stacked in the correct order :)

**Reproduce it**

I was able to reproduce the bug with a clean, freshly created app, and on the last release of the Twitter app for iPhone (by touching the "Loading" label with finger #1 and touching a tweet multiple times).

However, I could not trigger the same behaviour in the Settings app, under the "General" tab (which is a grouped table view).

The bug was reproduced on iOS 6.0 and 6.1. I don't have devices with older versions to test.

**Question**

Is this a known trick when creating navigation/table view based apps and if so is there a solution to prevent this (weird) behavior ? Or is this an iOS bug (and if so, is it already known from Apple) ?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this bug in my application - as soon as a cell is selected, a segue is pushed : I CANNOT select several cells like you do - so it might be related to the specific way your application (or others) handle segue push. One question : why do you have 3 segues on your storyboard between your table and the following viewController ? One should be enough

Comment: That was just to allow testing the segue on multiple cells. The table view contains static cells and I created a segue for each cell. My "real" app however uses dynamic cells, with only one segue (created with ctrl+drag onto the next controller, pretty classic). I just added to the question that I only tested on iOS 6.x. Are you testing on an earlier version ?

Comment: And you have this bug even when setting this segue as a 'custom' one, and doing things programmatically : calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` from your table delegate's `didSelectCellAtIndexPath:` ? 
This is the way I handle it, I cannot select several cells (iOS 6)

Comment: I was able to reproduce this bug

Comment: @Vinzzz Yes, I just reproduced the bug with this setup too. (Custom segue between controllers and calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:` from `didSelectCellAtIndexPath:`).

Comment: Ok, Segue style (modal/push/custom) seems in fact irrelevant. Is your segue triggered by cell selection from your storyboard ? (click on cell, check connections inspector, I have no segue linked here...). From you comment, it seems it doesn't, but I don't understand why I can't reproduce this multi-cell selection...

Comment: In the first setup (all storyboard based) yes, the segue is linked on the cell selection. On the setup you proposed (triggering the segue from `performSegueWithIdentifier:`), the segue is linked on the controller, not on the cell.

Comment: I reproduced the bug (I wasn't frenzy enough, now I consistently reproduce it in every UITableView ...)I vote iOS bug ! someone filled a radar ?

Comment: I also have this issue on this. And it is present in all version of iOS tested: 4.3, 5 ,6 and 7beta5.

However, Apple probably decided not to tackle this one, because it does not break applications, and no user will actually complain about it.

I am an iOS user since version 1, and until the QA department showed it to me, I never triggered it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed by Apple in iOS 7.

For prior versions of the OS, [Dan F's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15275764/404321) should do the trick.

Comment: I'm on iOS 12 now and am seeing this, so unless the bug was reintroduced I don't believe this comment is accurate. For clarification, I am manually calling `performSegue` inside of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 4):

A possible stop-gap measure you could use is to implement

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

And use a boolean flag or something to indicate that you are currently trying to execute that segue. ex:

```
BOOL doingSegue = NO;

-(void) viewWillAppear
{

    doingSegue = NO;
}

- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{

    if ( [identifier isEqualToString:@"MySegueIdentifier"] )
    {
        if ( doingSegue )
        {
            return NO;
        }
        else
        {
            doingSegue = YES;
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

**Swift Version**

```
var doingSegue = false

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    doingSegue = false
}

override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if identifier == "MySegueIdentifier" {
        if doingSegue {
            return false
        }
        else {
            doingSegue = true
            return true
        }
    }
    return true
}
```